# Quasar: drawerClick not working when I click one of menus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I would like to have responsive `drawer`, so tried to code in accordance with Quasar Docs, however, it was not resized properly when the screen size is being changed. In order to solve this, I used `computed` in the `script`. I think due to this `computed`, the function `drawerClick` not working.

When the drawer is on `minimode`, and one of menus are clicked, then the menu should be expanded, but the problem I have is it never expanded.

template

```js
<template>
  <q-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    show-if-above
    :mini="!drawer || miniState || miniStatus"
    @click.capture="drawerClick"
    :width="220"
    :breakpoint="500"
    bordered
    :content-style="{ backgroundColor: '#f5f7f9' }"
    id="side-menu"
  >
    <q-scroll-area class="fit">
      <q-list padding>
        <q-btn v-if="!miniState" flat left class="logo-btn">
          <img src="~assets/os_logo.png" width="144px" height="24px" contain />
        </q-btn>
        <q-btn v-else flat left>
          <img src="~assets/os_logo_no_text.png" width="24px" contain />
        </q-btn>

        <q-expansion-item
          default-opened
          v-for="(menu, index) in menus"
          header-class="header-bg text-black"
          expand-icon-class="text-gray"
        >
          <q-expansion-item
            v-for="(sub, index) in menu.subMenus"
            :key="index"
            :label="sub.title"
            expand-icon="none"
            class="sub-content"
            :to="{ name: sub.link }"
          />
        </q-expansion-item>
      </q-list>
    </q-scroll-area>
  </q-drawer>
</template>
```

script

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'SideMenu',
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      miniStatus: false,
      switchToMini: 700
    };
  },
  computed: {
    miniState: function() {
      return this.$q.screen.width < this.switchToMini;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    drawerClick(e) {
      if (this.miniStatus) {
        this.miniStatus = false;
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I explained better here in this image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqYoc.png